# Prepaid credit card for Wizzair flight

Tags: air-travel, payment-cards, wizz-air, pre-pay

Here in Germany we can buy prepaid credit cards in gas stations and put money on them.

I wanted to ask if anyone has any experience regarding if I could book a  Wizzair flight using one of these prepaid credit cards?

Answer (score 4):

Depends on the type of prepaid credit card you have. Wizzair accepts these cards:

> Credit and debit cards (Visa, Visa Electron, MasterCard, Maestro and UATP)

([Source](https://wizzair.com/en-gb/information-and-services/booking-information/payments/))

I don't have experience with this but if your card is one of those types I don't see why it can't be accepted. For more certainty you can contact Wizzair.

Answer (score 1):

Don't see why not. As long as Prepaid card is Visa or MasterCard there will be no issues. I used my prepaid Revolut card on multiple occasions for flight, bus or hotel bookings.

Comment: I wanted to get a visa one but tohught I'd ask because wizzair website itself doesn't have many options for paying, no transfer